# Jquery SimpleDialog not loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, simplemodal

I am working with Jquery simpleDialog.  I am watching fidler and it is telling me that it is loading the js files successfully. I reference the files correctly in my view and I make correct calls.  I am at my wits end and I can't quite figure out what to do.  I have been looking at this code for the last couple of hours and I haven't been able to budge it.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link href="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/simpleDialog/jquery.simpledialog.0.1.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/simpleDialog/jquery.simpledialog.0.1.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/simpleDialog/jquery.form.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('a.tempDlg1').simpleDialog({
            opacity: 0.3,
            duration: 200,
            width: 950,
            useTitleAttr: true,
            closeLabel: '<img src="../../Content/simpleDialog/CloseButton2.gif" border="1"/>',
            showCloseLabel: true
        });
    </script>
```

The simpleDialog window just won't open.  Does UIDialog work better?  I do have datePicker inside of this dialog.  Could that be affecting it?  I don't know, I have been working for 16 hours straight.  I need some sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing

```
});
```

for the `$(document).ready(function() {` block.

Comment: Your right, its not there in the example.  But it is in my code.  I am switching jquery libraries to see if I can't do this in a different way.